# Update query for a specfic columns in all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, linq, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I'm searching for check a columns value in all the rows and update with a where clause as a condition.  My case is as follows:

```
    SubscriptionID    ChannelURI    StudentID
        1               XXXX             4
        2               yyyy             4
        3               XXXX             3
        4               XXXX             4
        5               XXXX             2
```

I want to check the column channel uri value for a specfic student and for all matched results to set it to null.

So in this case row 3 and 5 should be set to null.

I've tried this, but it set all `channeluri` of other rows than `studnetid = 4` to null

```
UPDATE SubscriptionCourse 
   Set ChannelURI = 1
     , DeviceId = null 
  FROM SubscriptionCourse as t1 
 INNER JOIN SubscriptionCourse as t2 
    on t1.ChannelURI = t2.ChannelURI 
 WHERE StudentId! = 4
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of why rows 3 and 5 should be set to null, but other rows shouldn't?

Comment: You really need to provide a better description. It's not at all clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: sorry i didn't make it clear : i want to check all the channeluri in the table for all studentid other than student=4 , and if a match found to studentid=4 channel uri then set the matched row channeluri to null

Comment: And how do _you_ think you should do this?

Comment: UPDATE SubscriptionCourse Set ChannelURI = 1,DeviceId=null
FROM SubscriptionCourse as t1
INNER JOIN SubscriptionCourse as t2 on t1.ChannelURI = t2.ChannelURI 
WHERE StudentId! = 4
I've tried this , but it set all channeluri of others rows than studnetid=4 to null

Comment: I'll try to restate your question: For a given student ID, you want to search a table for a URI linked to that student. Then replace all matching URI's which are *not* associated with the same student ID with null. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

Reference the table to be updated by it's alias given in the FROM clause, rather than by name (since the same table name is referenced twice.  Also qualify the reference on StudentId in the WHERE clause with the table alias as well.

```
UPDATE t1
   SET t1.ChannelURI = 1
     , t1.DeviceId   = NULL
  FROM SubscriptionCourse t1 
  JOIN SubscriptionCourse t2
    ON t1.ChannelURI = t2.ChannelURI
 WHERE t1.StudentId != 4
```

You say you want to set ChannelURI to NULL, but your statement is setting to a literal value of 1. I've left the assignment as you specified in your statement, but qualified the columns with the table alias.

I don't think this is your problem, but I never include a space in the "not equals" comparison operator symbol (`!=`). I've just never seen that before. I prefer to use the `<>` symbol for the "not equals" comparison operator.

From your description of the problem and your example, it's not at all clear why you need to join the table to itself.

I recommend you FIRST write a SELECT statement that returns the rows you want to update, by replacing the `UPDATE` and `SET` clauses with a `SELECT <expression_list>` clause, with the expression_list including the value of the primary key column(s), the column you want to update, and any other columns you want to check. Once that SELECT is returning the rows you want to update, then convert it into an UPDATE statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
update [table_name] set channelURI = "null" where SubscriptionID = 3 or SubscriptionID =5
```

in this case,SubscriptionID    must be a primary key.

Comment: this is not the case , the where condition should be with StudentId , in the query you submitted , how would i know the subscriptionid , and if there was more than 2 matches?

Answer (score 0):

```
Update table set channeluri = null where studentid <> 4
```

That what you want? Or you want to find all the ones that have the same uri as student 4 and null those?

```
Update table set channeluri = null from table inner join table t2 on table.channeluri =t2.channeluri where table.studentid <> 4 and t2.studentid =4
```

Something like that, im on my phone, the wife has stolen the pc